# Install custom package from softaculous by API PHP

Tags: api, package, whm, softaculous

I need to install my custom package from softaculous by API. I have created a custom package in softaculous its working fine when I install from WHM but I need to install from API. If I install WordPress API then it's working. Wordpress is installed successfully. I am using below link for install package by API

https://softaculous.com/docs/API#Install_a_Script

In this section, you will see 26 is for WordPress. My package Id is 1001. When I set 1001 then my package will not install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID for custom scripts in Softaculous starts with 10001 (ten thousand and one) and it seems you are using 1001.

Please try with 10001 and I am sure it will work.

Do let me know if it does not work.